# Highcharts on web page and PhantomJS series rendering error

Tags: highcharts, phantomjs

I've currently got an existing application that uses Highcharts. Everything in the application works perfectly and in all browsers. The graph consists of multiple series all with different colours.

Recently I added the ability server side using PhantomJS to generate automated PDF reports from various of the application pages. Including the Highcharts rendered graph.

I do this using the following command:

```
phantomjs convertpage.js url file size
```

The convertpage.js contains the following:

```
var page = require('webpage').create(),
system = require('system'),
address, output, size;

if (system.args.length < 3 || system.args.length > 5) {
    console.log('Usage: rasterize.js URL filename [paperwidth*paperheight|paperformat] [zoom]');
    console.log('  paper (pdf output) examples: "5in*7.5in", "10cm*20cm", "A4", "Letter"');
    phantom.exit(1);
} else {
    address = system.args[1];
    output = system.args[2];
    page.viewportSize = { width: 600, height: 600 };
    if (system.args.length > 3 && system.args[2].substr(-4) === ".pdf") {
        size = system.args[3].split('*');
        page.paperSize = size.length === 2 ? { width: size[0], height: size[1], margin: '0px' }
                                       : { format: system.args[3], orientation: 'portrait', margin: '1cm' };
    }
    if (system.args.length > 4) {
        page.zoomFactor = system.args[4];
    }
    page.open(address, function (status) {
       if (status !== 'success') {
            console.log('Unable to load the address!');
            phantom.exit();
       } else {
        var timeout = address.indexOf('graphs')>-1 ? 20000 : 500;
        console.log('Timeout: '+timeout);
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            page.render(output);
            phantom.exit();
        }, timeout);
    }
 });
}
```

On the application page that is rendering chart I am setting the series in the following manner, which is working well on the pages themselves via a browser:

```
$.each(dbFields, function (key, field){
    var tmp = new Object();
    tmp.name = fieldsObject[key];
    tmp.color = colorsObject[key];
    tmp.data = filtered[field];
    tmp.min = 0;
    tmp.lineWidth = 1.5;
    seriesCalculated.push(tmp);
});
```

However, when I generate it using the script above and PhantomJS none of the colours are applied and neither the line thickness... it's simply a very thick light grey line for each series.

Any help/ideas would by much appreciated!

Sample of incorrect output can be found [here](http://dev.rightbrain.co.za/test.pdf)

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16084405/exporting-highcharts-polar-chart-to-pdf-with-phantomjs - There are answers over there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [exporting highcharts polar chart to PDF with phantomjs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16084405/exporting-highcharts-polar-chart-to-pdf-with-phantomjs)